# Iterative shrinkage algorithm for L1 optimization - A MATLAB Code testing

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, regularization

I am going to solve the problem:

$x =: \underset{x}{\text{argmin }}\frac{1}{2}||y-Ax||^2+||x||_1$

using iterative shrinkage algorithms (ISTA). There is a modified version know as FISTA which is as follows:

[image]

In order to see that I understand it, I wrote a MATLAB code to test if I am able to recover my sparse model, $x$ as in $Ax=y$. My code is as follows:

```
xorig = zeros(100,1);
xorig (5:15:end) = 10;
figure, plot(xorig)
A = magic(100)/10000;
figure, imagesc(A)
b = A*xorig;
xnoisy = xorig + randn(size(xorig));
x0 = xnoisy;

%---------------------------
tk = 1;
thrsh = 0.001;
landa = 2.5;
yk = x0;

for iter = 1:1000
  
     xk = wthresh(yk-landa*A'*(A*yk-b),'s',thrsh);
   
     tkk = (1+sqrt(1+4*tk^2))/2;
     ak = (tk-1)/tkk;
     ykk = xk+ak*(xk-x0);

     tk = tkk;
     yk = ykk; 
     x0 = xk;
end
```

My first question is that am I written the code right?
And if yes, why I can not recover proper $x$ ? (I have tested different values for step size (landa) and thresholding for shrinkage operator)

Second question is that is there any better way to choose parameters instead of testing for different values?

Comment: I advise you to post your very specialized question (using for example a function "wthresh" needing wavelet toolbox that I don't have) on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546638/denosing-signal-using-soft-and-hard-thresholding/24546961#24546961)

Comment: You should cite the origin of your image : https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~carlier/FISTA

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you, my question is actually about the mathematical point of view and whtresh function here is the proximal for L1-norm as far as I Know.